# Allowing users to purchase multiple products at a time using Google checkout

Tags: ecommerce, shopping-cart, google-checkout

Customers currently can't purchase more than 1 product at a time with Google Checkout.

For example, a customer wants to purchase 5 of the same product; the quantity will pass to Google Checkout page, but after placing the order using Google Checkout it will count it as one product.

Right now when you put in 2 items in the shopping cart and Google Checkout only calculates the shipping for the ORDER not for EACH ITEM.  Any help would be great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Might be a good time to ditch Google check out, you only have 5 months left until its gone any way.
https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449?hl=en

Comment: Okay Thanks for your valuable reply. I want continue with Google checkout upto November. Right now when you put in 2 items in the shopping cart and Google Checkout only calculates the shipping for the ORDER not for EACH ITEM. Any help would be great. Thanks a lot! How can isolve this issue?